# how to find the actual position of object in MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView multiAutoCompleteTextView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.multiAutoComplete);     
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,listName);
multiAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
multiAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
```

Comment: Give us a bit more context when asking a question please. What are you trying to do? Where do you use this code? What have you tried? You could read up on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question to improve readability.

Comment: as we do in the web when select any options from dropdown then there is option called "value" which we use as hidden id, so the same behavior i am expecting from multiautocompletetextview.
actually i have no idea that how to get the id from the position as i am not getting the exact position